# Number of data generated when a sql query is called or executed

Tags: java, oracle

When I run my java web application, I want to know when I execute a query in my application, how much data is coming and out in kilobyte? Is there a tool to do that?

Comment: May be not much helpful but just want to add .. are u using hibernate? there is a Interceptors that can help you AuditLog and your model should implement IAuditLog..

Comment: I'm using hibernate. I dont have auditLog. I just want to know when the query return me 15 rows, how much data is passed on the bandwidth?(kb/s)

Comment: As far as i know you may done it with sqlPlus with SET AUTOTRACE ON and you will see all detailed thing in result

Comment: ok how about enabling hibernate statistics  _<property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>_ and also getting it in your program using _SessionStatistics sessionStats = session.getStatistics();_ or 
_Statistics stats = this.sessionFactory.getStatistics();_

Answer (score 1):

you can run a select statement with vsize to check the size of the all data retrieved

example

```
SCOTT@research 16-APR-15> select * from test1;

      VAL1       VAL2       VAL3
---------- ---------- ----------
       555          2          4
         3          2          4
       123          2          3
        42          3

SCOTT@research 16-APR-15> select sum(vsize(val1)+vsize(val2)+vsize(val3)) "bytes" from test1;

     bytes
----------
        20


 SCOTT@research 16-APR-15> select sum(vsize(val1)+vsize(val2)+vsize(val3)) "bytes" from test1 where val3=3;

     bytes
 ---------
         7
```

If specifically kilo bytes then divide by 1024

```
SCOTT@research 16-APR-15> select sum(vsize(val1)+vsize(val2)+vsize(val3))/1024 "kilo bytes" from test1;

kilo bytes
----------
 .01953125
```

Answer (score 1):

> how much data is coming and out in kilobyte?

To see the **bytes expected to be read and transferred back** you could simply see the explain plan for the query.

For example,

```
SQL> explain plan for select * from emp;

Explained.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3956160932

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |    14 |   546 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |    14 |   546 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

8 rows selected.
```

So, you can see **546 bytes**.

To see the bytes for both **sent and received via SQL*Net**, you could **SET AUTOTRACE ON**.

For example,

```
SQL> SET AUTOTRACE ON
SQL> select empno from emp;

     EMPNO
----------
      7369
      7499
      7521
      7566
      7654
      7698
      7782
      7788
      7839
      7844
      7876
      7900
      7902
      7934

14 rows selected.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 179099197

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |        |    14 |    56 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  INDEX FULL SCAN | PK_EMP |    14 |    56 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          8  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          4  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
        702  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        544  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
         14  rows processed

SQL>
```

So, you can see **702  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client*** and **544  bytes received via SQLNet from client**.

Comment: This is at database level.  I want it at runtime. When I query from my java web application, how much kilobyte is going on the bandwidth. Is it possible?

Comment: When you are querying, you are already hitting the database. So, you could fetch this information.

Comment: Is it possible for you to `SPOOL` this and read the spool data? Or, some function is Java which does the same thing as using AUTOTRACE.